# Get jQuery to measure with em instead of px

Tags: html, jquery, font-size

I have a website that is heavily based on jQuery; meaning much of it's content is created, measured, & set by jQuery.

All these measurements are px. I need to either convert them to em or, preferably, create a function that will convert them for me. This would be easy if all the font-size was 16px (or 100%); this is not the case, however. I need it to detect the font-size of the container & go from there.

Comment: We really need to see some code to answer. I think that having css classes do the work and jQuery adds classes to the HTML, however, without seeing code I don't know if this is the way to proceed.

Comment: There is WAY too much code to show; & no that would not work. I'm creating elements & styles dynamically & I'm detecting measurements like the width of something & setting it as a var & setting another element's position, for instance, = that var. I hope that can help to clarify?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to create the classes dynamically and you couldn't have them in a css file and just change the classes of dom elements in jQuery?

Comment: Yes. It is a large extensive interactive site where things will constantly be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3JsKP/1/).

```
          function px_to_em(px_value, container) {
          ////////////////////////////////
          // Detect Contianer Font Size //
          ////////////////////////////////

          //Prepend a span tag to the container for testing
          $(container).prepend("<span id='wraping_span_to_test'></span>");

          //Set the span to height 1em and then save the pixel height to the container_ft_sz variable
          container_ft_size = $("#wraping_span_to_test").css({
              "font-family": "inherit",
                  "font-size": "inherit",
                  "font-style": "inherit",
                  "font-variant": "inherit",
                  "font-weight": "inherit",
                  "line-height": "inherit",
                  "margin": "0 !important",
                  "padding": "0 !important",
                  "border": "0 !important",
                  "outline": "0 !important",
                  "background-color": "aqua",
                  "height": "1em",
                  "width": " 1em",
                  "display": "block"
          }).height();

          //Remove the testing span
          $("#wraping_span_to_test").remove();

          //Use values to convert to ems
          var round_to = 1000;
          return Math.round((px_value / container_ft_size) * round_to) / round_to;
      }
```

This should allow you to find measurements with jQuery that is measured by pixels & convert them into em measurements by calling a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy. Thinking about it you could temporarily insert content with width:1em, measure the width in px, and calculate the em you need from there.

Comment: I fail to see how this solution will get me the results I need as ems are based on font-size. Could you elaborate more or give an example?